# Wrong PC-projector resolution in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution, projector

I'm connecting a PC-projector (Benq MP721) to a Windows 7 Professional laptop (HP 6730b). All the output settings on the laptop, including the laptop screen, changes to 1024x768 (which the projector supports). However the projector says it receives 1360x768 and asks me to change the resolution to 1024x768.

- I'm using mirrored display.
- The laptop is 1024x768
- The screen resolution in the control panel says 1024x768
- The Intel graphics card utilities says 1024x768
- The driver for the projector is a Generic PnP Monitor

Is there anything in Windows 7 that would convert my 4:3 resolution to wide screen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing with different computers:
There is no problem with Windows 7.

It turns out that the driver (8.15.0010.1855) for Intel GMA X4500MHD is buggy.
There is currently a new driver on the Intel webside that can be forced to load via the control panel. The HP driver is still not updated.